# Very sudden 80% decrease in CPU performance

Tags: cpu, performance, hardware-failure, desktop-computer, cpu-usage

https://prnt.sc/jap0kx

In the above screenshot are benchmarks for my CPU, right is from 6 April and left is from today. As you can see, there's been a sudden 80% decrease in benchmark performance.

Over the past two days my computer started running running the CPU at 100% during basic tasks like watching YouTube videos or pretty much anything else.

At first I thought I may have gotten a virus, and scanned my PC with Kaspersky, Superantispyware and Anti-Malware Bytes, nothing came up.

I tinkered with the bios, and reset everything to default, and still nothing.

Here is a open hardware report : https://www.dropbox.com/s/r9qzkbyudxqhrvg/report%20AH.txt?dl=0

The CPU runs roughly 4°C lower than a what it did previously, and draws very little power. The CPU fan which has previously always ran at a solid 2K RPM is now hovering around 1.4 K, this has never happened before.

The computer is pretty old by now, soon to be five years old, so perhaps hardware failure is to blame, though I'm not certain how to confirm this.

If anyone has an idea for how to fix this, or what might even be the cause, I would very much appreciate,

PS if you need any additional information, don't hesitate asking.

Comment: Do you have a spare PSU to test with?

Comment: Sadly I do not, do you think this may be PSU related?

Comment: If the PSU is not providing enough power on one or more voltage rails then it could cause the CPU to underclock. I would say it's also worth trying a live CD or something to see if your CPU ever reaches a decent clock speed in case something is really messed up with your Windows installation.

Comment: What is a live CD?

Comment: It's just a way of running an OS (e.g. Ubuntu Linux) from a CD/DVD directly without actually installing anything. Nowadays people tend to install on USB drives instead and run from there but it doesn't make much difference. The advantage is that it allows you to rule out software issues without permanently changing anything on your PC

Comment: Have you checked your Power Options in Windows? Make sure it's set to High Performance. Then if you click **change advanced power settings** for that profile it should have a Processor power management section - check that **maximum processor state** is set to 100%.

Comment: The CPU worked all fine and Linux, so after going back to Windows and checking my power plan, I saw that for some reason the CPU was limited to 5% performance... So now everything is all right. Thank you so much of help

Comment: Yes I thought it might be that, looks like I wrote the comment just a few seconds before you did. Would you like me to change them to an answer? I would also add that some buggy piece of software may be changing your power settings so the issue could reoccur - if so then you would need to check if anything has been installed or updated recently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah I had something similiar and it turned out to be psu not delivering enough power anymore.
There is a tool called hwinfo that might help that you can download which shows current..otherwise you would have to use a power meter on the psu to check.

Comment: Do these numbers mean anything to you?

Voltages seems quite low, and CPU power draw is low too. https://www.dropbox.com/s/p28btw4eqgwek13/hwinfo.CSV?dl=0